# OpenLayers zoom when changing layer

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openlayers, openstreetmap, zooming

I am working on a mobile application using OpenLayers maps. There I have three different layers. Layers are in idifferent projections so i transform extents and everything connected to their placement.

When I change layer - the map zooms out for a 1 and every time when I change layer - map zooms out a bit.

I already tried adding 1 or 2 for "map.getZoom" but it didn't work either.

What could cause this strange behaviour? I can attach the needed code if it helps.

```
function showOsm() {

    var extent = map.getExtent();

    zoom = map.getZoom();
    var center = map.getCenter();

    var oldProjection = map.getProjectionObject().getCode();

    map.setBaseLayer(osmLayer);

    extentOsm = extent.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection(oldProjection), map
            .getProjectionObject());

    koko = 1;

    center = center.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection(oldProjection), map
            .getProjectionObject());

    estateBoundsOverlay.setVisibility(false);
    taskPoints.removeAllFeatures();

function showMml() {

    var extent = map.getExtent();

    zoom = map.getZoom();
    var center = map.getCenter();

    var oldProjection = map.getProjectionObject().getCode();

    if (firstStart){
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
    }

    map.setBaseLayer(layer);

    extentMml = extent.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection(oldProjection), map
            .getProjectionObject());

    center = center.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection(oldProjection), map
            .getProjectionObject());

    taskPoints.removeAllFeatures();
```

These functions call layers (map.setBaseLayer - this one makes layer visible). And I have standard layer properties (with maxExtent, restrictedExtent, zoomLevels, projection and displayProjection).

Comment: show some codes please

Comment: Here is the sample code.

Comment: Maybe your firstart detection is wrong and is triggered even if a layer is (un)hidden?